# Tomcat: Allow users with certain ips (remoteaddrvalve) unrestricted access but other must authenticate

Tags: tomcat

I want users within a certain address range (within my workplace) unrestricted access to a web application, but want all others to hit an authentication page (set up conventionally in web.xml).

I am struggling to see how to mix remoteaddrvalve or remotehostvalue with authentication. Basically we need restrict and audit external users but let internal users free access without the pain of login.

Can anyone help ?

Using Spring security is also an option. Server is tomcat 7.